# An error occurred in the secure channel support WSL

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
wsl --install
Windows Subsystem for Linux is already installed.
An error occurred in the secure channel support
wsl --list --online
An error occurred in the secure channel support
```

how to make it work?
i also selected ssl 3.0 from the internet options and TLS 1.2,1.3 are checked too. it still doesn't work.

Comment: Keep in mind that questions on Stack Overflow should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems" (i.e. "unique to software development")*. For information on how to determine if a WSL question is programming-related (and where to post if it isn't), please see the [WSL tag-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-subsystem-for-linux/info).  Thanks!